# biblatex-dw: redefine text formatting for specific entry type (incollection)

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-dw

I am using `biblatex-dw` with the BibTeX8 backend and option `namefont=italic,`

In the footnotes, this works great: https://www.screencast.com/t/Df8hOSYzd0S

In the bibliography, it is absolutely perfect for authors and editors in most entry types: https://www.screencast.com/t/sDpI3QVQ

- author = always italic: perfect
- editor = italic when type=`@book` perfect
- **editor = should not be italic if entry type is `@incollection`**

So I guess I need an exception for entry type `@incollection` only, but I have no idea how to solve this...

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{literatur.bib}
@Book{archiv-verwaltung1919,
  Title                    = {Geschichte der Archiv-Verwaltung bei dem Deutschen Generalgouvernement Warschau},
  Editor                   = {{Archiv-Verwaltung des Deutschen Generalgouvernements Warschau}},
  Publisher                = {Mittler},
  Year                     = {1919},

  Address                  = {Berlin},
  Shorttitle               = {Archiv-Verwaltung},

  __markedentry            = {[tw:1]},
  Abstract                 = {Aufsätze 32 Exzerpt vorhanden},
  Owner                    = {tw},
  Timestamp                = {2014.12.11}
}

@Book{deutscheostforschung1,
  Title                    = {Deutsche Ostforschung. Ergebnisse und Aufgaben seit dem ersten Weltkrieg. Erster Band},
  Editor                   = {Aubin, Hermann and Brunner, Otto and Kohte, Wolfgang and Papritz, Johannes},
  Publisher                = {Hirzel},
  Year                     = {1942},

  Address                  = {Leipzig},
  Shorttitle               = {Ostforschung I},

  __markedentry            = {[tw:1]},
  Owner                    = {tw},
  Timestamp                = {2016.03.22}
} 
@Incollection{ash2006,
  Title                    = {Wissenschaftswandlungen und politische Umbrüche im 20. Jahrhundert -- was hatten sie miteinander zu tun?},
  Author                   = {Ash, Mitchell G.},
  Booktitle                = {Kontinuitäten und Diskontinuitäten in der Wissenschaftsgeschichte des 20. Jahrhunderts},
  Publisher                = {Steiner},
  Year                     = {2006},

  Address                  = {Stuttgart},
  Editor                   = {vom Bruch, Rüdiger and Gerhardt, Uta and Pawliczek, Aleksandra},
  Pages                    = {S. 19-38},
  Shorttitle               = {Wissenschaftswandlungen},

  Abstract                 = {Exzerpt vorhanden Aufsätze 9},
  Owner                    = {tw},
  Timestamp                = {2013.05.14}
}

@Incollection{arnold-etal2009,
  Title                    = {Tod, Zerstörung, Wiederaufbau. Zu einer europäischen Erinnerungsgeschichte des Luftkriegs},
  Author                   = {Arnold, Jörg and Süß, Dietmar and Thießen, Malte},
  Booktitle                = {Luftkrieg. Erinnerungen in Deutschland und Europa},
  Publisher                = {Wallstein},
  Year                     = {2009},

  Address                  = {Göttingen},
  Editor                   = {Arnold, Jörg and Süß, Dietmar and Thießen, Malte},
  Pages                    = {S. 9-26},
  Shorttitle               = {Erinnerungsgeschichte},

  Owner                    = {tw},
  Timestamp                = {2016.03.28}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=10pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{times} 

\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,
                        style=authortitle-dw,
                        namefont=italic,
                        idembib=false,
                        sorting=nty,
                        hyperref=false,
                        edbyidem=false,
                        ]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\addbibresource{literatur.bib} 

\begin{document}
kjsdb\footcite{archiv-verwaltung1919}jkd\footcite{deutscheostforschung1}sbfsjkdbfsdjk\footcite{armbruster2007} kjsddh\footcite{ash2006}fkjdsh hsdjkfhdsjfhdsj fdsh hwhsdjkfh sdkjh

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no convenient way to hook in `biblatex` to format only the primary name (i.e. the name that is printed as the first name in `sortname` format and usually goes into `labelname`). I have long thought that it would be a good idea to have something like this, but I have not found a convenient way to implement it yet, suggestions are welcome.

With `biblatex-dw`'s `authortitle-dw` the following trick should do it: We set `namefont=normal` and effectively switch it to `italic` for citations with the help of `\AtEveryCite`, for the bibliography we use a special format for `sortname`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,
                        style=authortitle-dw,
                        namefont=normal,%      <- change this to 'normal'
                        idembib=false,
                        sorting=nty,
                        hyperref=false,
                        edbyidem=false,
                        ]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryCite{\renewcommand{\bbx@namefont}{\mkbibemph}}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given-namefont-italic}
\DeclareNameFormat{family-given-namefont-italic}{%
  \renewcommand{\bbx@namefont}{\mkbibemph}%
  \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} 

\begin{document}
Lorem\footcite{westfahl:space} ipsum\footcite{westfahl:frontier} dolor\footcite{sigfridsson} sit\footcite{brandt,moraux}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

This would not work for `footnote-dw`.

Comment: @binsky Brilliant! I just noticed I had forgotten a `%` and edited in.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I also added the % and compiled again; doesn't look like this had any effects

Comment: @binsky It did actually, compare the position of the first letter in each bibliography entry with and without the `%`. Without `%` each entry is slightly indented to the right because an unwanted space starts the entry instead of the first letter. It is more visible if you compare the position with respect to the heading "Literatur".

Comment: indeed, you're absolutely right; thanks for the hint, very appreciated

Comment: this solution not only works in my MWE but also in my main text/thesis. But in there, I realized this solution had influence on the footnotes and the whole document. Instead of 606 there are 604 pages if I use this workaround to get some editors non-italic. But these editors aren't mentioned in the footnotes, what makes me wonder...  This shouldn't be a problem in general, but in this case, the publisher has already approved the whole document except the issue in the bibliography and would not be happy to re-check it completely because of new line-&page-breaks etc. Any idea for that?

Comment: @binsky Mhhh, I would have thought it unlikely that that small a change could cause a difference in two pages, but it is not entirely inconceivable. Roman and italic shapes have slightly different widths and in a long bibliography that may very well cause different line and page breaks. Ideally the change should only influence the bibliography, so if you could double check that only the bibliography is affected only that would have to be re-checked. Of course I can't guarantee that I made a mistake and did not think of an edge case that causes more change than intended. ...

Comment: ... Either way a thorough look is needed.

Comment: @binsky If you can find a discrepancy between the earlier (intended) output and my solution here I would be interested to hear about it in an MWE. I can't promise that I will be able to find a fix, but I will definitely have a look.

Comment: what makes me wonder is that the differences of two pages (in total) appear in the main text because of slightly different footnotes and line/pagebreaks. I would totally understand if the bibliography itself would be some pages shorter or longer, but in here I have differences in handling the main parts, too.

Comment: @binsky Mhh, can you find out a difference in output that could cause different page breaking? What is the first difference between the old and the new output?

Comment: but what I just recognized: the last version of my "old" version which differs from the new one with your solution (606 vs 604 pages) was compiled on another computer, so I have to check if there were used exactly the same parameters, as this could cause those changes, too. Mainly, I guess there are differences in miktex and texniccenter on these two machines (32bit vs 64bit versions, settings to be checked). I will try your solution on the main computer as soon as I am at home today.

Comment: was just able to make another test: I just compiled my last version (without your solution) again on the computer I am using at the moment, and I get also two pages less. So I have differences in parameters or package versions or something like that, but it's obviously not caused by your solution, which is definitely working well and just does what it is supposed to! I will check again with the other machine this evening, but that should proof it.